# How to set onClick with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the onclick event using javascript.  The following code works:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', "#");
link.setAttribute('onclick', "alert('click')");
```

I then use appendChild to add link to the rest of the document.

But I obviously would like a more complicated callback than alert, so I tried this:

```
link.onclick = function() {alert('clicked');};
```

and this:

```
link.onclick = (function() {alert('clicked');});
```

But that does nothing.  When I click the link, nothing happens.  I have testing using chrome and browsing the DOM object shows me for that element that the onclick attribute is NULL.

Why am I not able to pass a function into onclick?

EDIT:

I tried using addEventListener as suggested below with the same results.  The DOM for the link shows onclick as null.

My problem may be that the DOM for this element might not have been fully built yet.  At this point the page has been loaded and the user clicks a button.  The button executes javascript that builds up a new div that it appends to the page by calling document.body.appendChild.  This link is a member of the new div.  If this is my problem, how do I work around it?

Comment: Try `addEventListener('click', function() {...})`

Comment: I actually end up writing [an article](http://heyjavascript.com/setting-and-changing-the-onclick-attribute-with-javascript/) about this.

Comment: `link.onclick = function () { ... };` should work: http://jsfiddle.net/sZHkt/1/

Comment: Works for me , not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: In your article, you mention to be careful to make sure the DOM is ready to be manipulated.  Perhaps my problem is I am trying to set onclick too soon?  I am building up an entire div and appending it to the page after the page has loaded.  So the page loads, the user clicks a button that runs javascript that creates a div with my link inside it.  Do I need to do something to make sure the link is built before I can set the onclick?

Comment: I saw the question was edited. Before I try to answer it with the help of the new information provided, could you please check if http://jsfiddle.net/6MjgB/7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/6MjgB/8/ work on your browser?

Comment: Both your links work.  The javascript for setting the onclick is correct and SHOULD work, like everyone is saying, but for some reason in my script, it doesn't.  I tried getting an example outside of my environment that reproduces the error, but haven't been able to do so.

Comment: I've had the same problem, I had to use the `setAttribute()` method of altering the elements after the `DOMContentLoaded` had fired. I think it's something to do with using MAMP on my Mac - in my case.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have been unable to reproduce the problem.  Contrary to the OP's findings, the line below works fine on the latest versions of IE, FF, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

```
link.onclick = function() {alert('clicked');};
```

You can visit this jsFiddle to test on your own browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/6MjgB/7/

Assuning we have this in the html page:

```
<div id="x"></div>
```

The following code works fine on the browsers I have tried it with:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hi"));
link.setAttribute('href', "#");
link.onclick= function() {link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Clicked"));}

document.getElementById("x").appendChild(link);
```

If there is a browser compatibility issue, using jQuery should solve it and make code much much more concise:

```
var $link = $("<a>").html("Hi").attr("href","#").click(function (){$link.html("Clicked")})

$("#x").html($link)
```

If brevity is not a strong enough argument for using jQuery, browser compatibility should be ... and vise versa :-)

NOTE: I am not using alert() in the code because jsFiddle does not seem to like it :-(

Comment: I have no idea why it wasn't working before, but the jquery code seems to have magically fixed whatever was wrong.

Comment: jsfiddle doesnt allow alert because someone can easily make a fiddle like `while(true) alert("gotcha sucka")`, and I dont think I need to explain why that's an issue

Comment: @Werlious I may be confused, but why it would be problem? JSfiddle runs sandboxed code on client, right?

Comment: Yes, so let's say I share a fiddle with you. You won't know until you open it, but the JS in the fiddle is `while(true) alert("harhar")`. You open the fiddle to see what it is, and when jsfiddle loads the fiddle, it also generates the preview, which runs the js, and now your computer is spamming alerts at you, generally slowing down your browser/computer faster than you can react. Now you have been DOSed. Replace that with say an infected image on say a stagefright era android and now you have some real problems

Answer (score 11):

If you're doing this with JavaScript, then use [**`addEventListener()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), with `addEventListener('click', function(e) {...})` to get the event stored as `e`.  If you don't pass in the event like this, it will not be accessible (although Chrome appears to be smart enough to figure this out, not all browsers are Chrome).

**[Full Working JSBin Demo.](https://jsbin.com/bajatoxizu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

*StackOverflow Demo...*

```js
document.getElementById('my-link').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Click happened for: ' + e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="my-link">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add a DOM even listener with `addEventListener(...)`, as David said. I've included `attachEvent` for compatibility with IE.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', "#");
if(link.addEventListener){
   link.addEventListener('click', function(){
      alert('clicked');
   });
}else if(link.attachEvent){
   link.attachEvent('onclick', function(){
      alert('clicked');
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting an attribute doesn't look right. The simplest way is just this:

```
link.onclick = function() {
    alert('click');
};
```

But using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) as JCOC611 suggested is more flexible, as it allows you to bind multiple event handlers to the same element. Keep in mind you might need a fallback to [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for compatibility with older Internet Explorer versions.

Answer (score 2):

Use sth like this if you like:

```
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick=function(){displayDate()};

function displayDate()
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *named function*, i.e., `function funcName() {...}` already defined, then the process is simply to identify `onclick` with the name of the function:

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = displayDate;

function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

This can help keep your code better organized.  A function can be quite long, and defining it singularly to a single `onclick`, and not some independent variable that can be referenced later, might end up creating spaghetti code.