# How to define onClick() function inside addEventListener()

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty to know how to fix "sayHello is not definedat HTMLButtonElement.onclick" issue.When I click on button this message is appeared in console.Can anybody help me please? I just want same working solution.

```
<button class="btn" onclick="sayHello()">Say Hello</button>

window.addEventListener('load',function(){

       function sayHello() {
         console.log("Hello Console!");
       }
});
```

Comment: What is it you're ultimately trying to accomplish here? Why is `sayHello` defined inside an event listener?

Answer (score 1):

You use `addEventListner()` to attach event handlers to objects so you don't need to attach them inline (which is considered bad practice by lot of people). You can do this easily within the window load handler as you can see in my example below.

That way you can simply add a click event handler. I recommend to use `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` to select the correct element(s) with css selectors.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("Hello Console!");
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">Say Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the sayHello function with an anonymous function.

You could simply move the say hello function into a script tag and reference in the same way you currently have in the onClick button attribute and this should work fine.

There is no need for the additional add event listener call when hooking up an onClick handler for a button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `sayHello` function outside the `addEventListener` callback.

```js
function sayHello() {
  console.log("Hello Console!");
}
window.addEventListener('load', sayHello);
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="sayHello()">Say Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will not work: `sayHello` is in a scope not accessible by the root scope

You can edit both html and js in this way:

Your html code: (note the usage of `id`)

```
<button id="foo" class="btn" >Say Hello</button>
```

Your js code:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  document.getElementById("foo").onclick=function() {
    console.log("Hello Console!");
  };  
});
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637133/how-to-set-onclick-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the window load event and check if it works. If not than entirely use javascript for attaching click event on the button by giving it an id of btn-1 and

```
document.getElementById('btn-1').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log("Hello Console!");
})
```