# How to set onclick for element when created with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i set the `onclick` property for an element  like link or button when  it's created with Javascript or how can i set an eventListener?

I create the Button with JavaScript, set an Id and add a Class.

```
var button=document.createElement('button')
button.className="btn btn-sm btn-danger listening_class_for_delete"
button.appendChild(delete_text_button)
button.setAttribute('id',id);
// how can i set 'onclick' here
// output shall be: 
<button ... onClick="functionName"></button>
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637133/how-to-set-onclick-with-javascript). It is the same question.

Comment: um, [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set onClick with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637133/how-to-set-onclick-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should make it:

`document.getElementById(id).onclick = function() { }`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using javascript you can add the onclick event listener directly to your script:

```
button.addEventListener('click', functionName);
```

If it is important for you to have it in the tag you can do the following with javascript:

```
document.querySelector('#button').setAttribute('onclick', 'functionName');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add an onclick function to your button element like so:

1.

```
button.onclick = () => {
  alert("onclick 1!");
};
```

2. 

```
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{alert("onclick 2!")}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <script>
      window.onload = () => {
        let div = document.getElementById("div");
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = "Click here";
        button.className = "btn btn-sm btn-danger listening_class_for_delete";
        div.appendChild(button);
        button.setAttribute("id", "id");
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let p = document.createElement("p");

          p.innerText = "Clicked";

          div.appendChild(p);
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```