# How to use clearInterval with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery (02 months), I'm trying to create a simple timer, but it isn't working when I click on the stop button. Could someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>Number of seconds on page: <span id="counter">0</span></h3>
<input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop Counting">
<script>
const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector);

let counter=0;
const timer = setInterval( () => {
counter++;
$("#counter").textContent = counter;
}, 1000);

$("#stop").click(function() {
clearInterval(timer);
});

</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't use jQuery on your code anywhere

Comment: Your question is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637133/how-to-set-onclick-with-javascript. click() is a method used to emulate a click. onclick is the property that defines what shall happen if a click occurs.

Comment: You're blurring the difference between `javascript` and `jquery`. jquery is written in javascript, but javascript does not require jquery. Anytime you put code inside of a `$()`, you're calling a jquery method. The `$` character is just a variable, so by declaring it as something else, you loose all of the jquery methods. `textContent` is a javascript property, equivalent to the jquery method `.text()` Remove the `const $ = ...` and change `$("#counter").textContent = counter;` to `$("#counter").text(counter);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `$` in your script making yourself - and even me - believe for a while that you were using jQuery. In reality you weren't. And that was the reason why your script did not work. The jQuery method `click` is not the same as the DOM element's method of the same name. You need to use either `.addEventListener("click",...)` or simply `.onclick=...` if you want to bind a handler function to the click event of that element.

I replaced your `$` with an equally short but hopefully less confusing `qs` and removed jQuery from the script altogether, as it isn't really needed anymore.

```html
<body>
<h3>Number of seconds on page: <span id="counter">0</span></h3>
<input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop Counting">
<script>
const qs=sel=>document.querySelector(sel);
let counter=0;
const timer = setInterval( () => {
counter++;
qs("#counter").textContent = counter;
}, 1000);

qs("#stop").onclick=ev=>{
clearInterval(timer);
};

</script>  
</body>
```